# How does murder interact with a creature being sacrificed?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

### if I cast [murder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bmurder%5d) on my opponent's creature that has a tap to sacrifice creature after he uses it's ability, does the activated ability happen?

My friends and I had a game where one of them used a tap ability to sacrifice this creature to deal 2 damage and I played [murder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bmurder%5d).

In response does my creature die or his ability not go off since the sacrifice was not a part of the cost?

Comment: Which creature was this effect on? The specific wording is important.

Comment: Please clarify.

Comment: The instruction to sacrifice the creature will probably be either in the cost to activate the ability (before the ":") or be an effect (after the ":"). If it is a cost, which is usually the case, you will not be able to target it with murder if your opponent already used the ability. Sacrificing it is a cost to using the ability, meaning it is already dead by the time effect goes on the stack. If the sacrifice is part of the effect, you will be able to murder it before the ability resolves. (The creature will die either way, but it may be important that it wasn't sacrificed.)